# are heels coming up when you squat an illegal lift for powerlifting competitions?

Tags: weightlifting, powerlifting

I know it is on the bench but I'm not sure for the squat

Comment: Are you asking if your lift doesn't count in a competition if you lift your heels during a squat?

Answer (score 8):

This is taken from the IPF rulebook, see rule 4 in particular:

> **Causes for disqualification of a Squat:**
>
> 1. Failure to observe the Chief Referee’s signals at the commencement
>      or completion of a lift.
>
>    2. Double bouncing at the bottom of the lift, or any downward movement during the ascent.
>    3. Failure to assume an upright position with the knees locked at the commencement or completion of the lift.
>    4. Stepping backward or forward or moving the feet laterally. **Rocking the feet between the ball and heel is permitted.**
>    5. Failure to bend the knees and lower the body until the top surface of the legs at the hip joint is lower than the top of the
>         knees, as in the diagram.
>    6. Contact with the bar or the lifter by the spotter / loaders between the Chief Referee’s signals in order to make the lift
>         easier.
>    7. Contact of the elbows or upper arms with the legs. Slight contact is permitted if there is no supporting that might aid the
>         lifter.
>    8. Any dropping or dumping of the bar after completion of the lift.
>    9. Failure to comply with any of the items outlined under Rules of Performance for the squat.

[IPF rulebook](http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/fileadmin/ipf/data/rules/technical-rules/english/2015_V2_IPF_Technical_Rules_Book_2015_classic_rules_in_back_section.pdf)